# object not saving to cart in django

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I am trying to add object to cart but nothing is added.  I'm pretty new to Django any help is appreciated.  Also I think the error has to do with my cart_update function.  In the tutorial this is how I wrote but when I was looking up this issue I found out I should be using get_object_or_404.  When I tried that way I was still unsuccessful with adding objects to the cart.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import os
import random
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.urls import reverse 
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from .utils import unique_slug_generator

def get_filename_ext(filepath):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    return name, ext

def upload_image_path(instance, filename):
    new_filename = random.randint(1,233434234)
    name, ext = get_filename_ext(filename)
    final_filename = '{new_filename}{ext}'.format(new_filename=new_filename, ext=ext)
    return "products/{new_filename}/{final_filename}".format(new_filename=new_filename, final_filename=final_filename)


class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)

    def featured(self):
        return self.filter(featured=True, active=True)

    def search(self,query):
        lookups = (Q(title__icontains=query) | 
                   Q(description__icontains=query) |
                   Q(price__icontains=query) |
                   Q(tag__title__icontains=query)
                    )
        return self.filter(lookups).distinct()

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def all(self):
        return self.get_queryset().active()

    def featured(self):
        return self.get_queryset().featured()

    def get_by_id(self,id):
        qs = self.get.queryset().filter(id=id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first()
        return None

    def search(self,query):
        return self.get_queryset().active().search(query)

class Product(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug            = models.SlugField(blank=True,unique=True)
    description     = models.TextField()
    price           = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20,default=10.99)
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery',null=True,blank=True)
    featured        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active          = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ProductManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
#        return "/products/{slug}/".format(slug=self.slug)
         return reverse("products:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

def product_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)

pre_save.connect(product_pre_save_receiver, sender=Product)
```

In this view is my cart_update function where the issue happens.

Cart/views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from products.models import Product
from .models import Cart


def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    products = cart_obj.products.all()

    return render(request, 'carts/home.html', {})

def cart_update(request):
    product_id = 1 #request.POST.get('product_id')
#    print(Product.objects.get(id=1))
    if product_id is not None:
        try:
            product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            print("show message to user ,Product is gone")
            return redirect("cart:home")
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if product_id in cart_obj.products.all():
            cart_obj.products.remove(product_obj)
        else:    
            cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
    #    return redirect(product_obj.get_absolute_url())
    return redirect("cart:home")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things you could improve in your code:

1) If the product does not exist (you are "hardwiring" `product_id` to be `1`, it might be the case) use [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#using-logging), there are situations `print` statement won't be enough.

2) If the product is already in the cart, you remove it leaving the cart empty. You could perhaps increase quantity?

3) The condition `if product_id in cart_obj.products.all()` will always be `False`
`cart_obj.products.all()` will return a queryset for `Product` not the id values, you have two options there:

```
if product_id in cart_obj.products.values_list("id", flat=True)
```

or

```
if product_obj in cart_obj.products.all()
```

4) I've not seen your `'carts/home.html'` template, but in your view `cart_home`, you're not adding products to the view context and, by the way, since you can access products within a basket through the basket itself (they are related), you don't need the line `products = cart_obj.products.all()`. Just add the `cart_obj` to the view context

```
def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    return render(request, 'carts/home.html', {"cart": cart_obj})
```

and write code like the following to your template:

```
<ul>
{% for product in cart.products.all %}
    <li>{{ product.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Hope you can find the error when checking one of those, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks Raydel for your very detailed answer this helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check `new_obj` for occurancies of the searched item, as far as I understand...